# Angular 6 extract value from decoded string base 64

Tags: angular, typescript, base64

I've decoded a string in Base64 with xml2js library and i got this value :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="293" height="102"
 viewBox="0 0 293 102"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny">
<image 
width="293" 
height="102" 
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS......pASYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
</svg>
```

i cut the encode value because it's to long

I'm blocked for getting the value of xlink:href, is there any technics or library for getting the attribute ?

I mean i want to get this value only : `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS......pASYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=`

Thank's

Comment: You could try using a regex to match only that part of the string. Something like `/xlink:href="([^"]*)"/`

Comment: It's a svg you can parse it using DOMParser

Comment: @JEY that's probably the most robust solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the xml string. Then you can operate on the resulting Document as usual:

```js
const xmlString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="293" height="102"
 viewBox="0 0 293 102"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny">
<image 
width="293" 
height="102" 
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS......pASYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
</svg>`;

const domParser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');
const imageElement = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('image')[0];
const hrefAttr = imageElement.getAttribute('xlink:href');
console.log(hrefAttr);
```

Comment: just use querySelector and getAttributeNS like i did https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yx3fyn

Comment: I've use this : var urlImage = xml.match(/xlink:href="([^"]*)"/); 
var finalUrl = urlImage[1] and it works

Thank's @Alex K and Jey for your solutions